# Netbeans Platform untrusted plugins

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform

Our application is based in the netbeans platform, we deploy the plugins (nbms) with signature using a code signing certificate.

The problem is that when the plugin is installed into our application there is a message alert showing that the plugins are signed but untrusted.

Can someone show me how to deploy trusted and signed plugins? I see that even the netbeans plugins installed via auto update are untrusted and self-signed.

Another possibility for me would be to disable this verification at all.

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone show me how to deploy trusted and signed plugins?

You don't mention which version of NetBeans you are using, but I suspect that you are doing everything correctly and there is a bug in NetBeans.

See this open NetBeans bug [Bug 271770 - Warning message for untrusted plugins needs to be improved](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=271770), where someone reports a similar problem:

```
I have a plugin that show signed but not trusted warning, although show certificate 
button does have certificate from digicert.

Following is detail of certificate.
Subject: CN=DigiCert SHA2 Assured ID Code Signing CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert 
Inc, C=US

Can anybody have idea what else needs to be done to make it trusted, and avoid    
warning.
```

If the problem is with NetBeans there is probably nothing you can change to make things work, but there are still some things you can do:

- If the issue is with NetBeans 8.x then update the bug report linked above to add your voice.
- If you haven't tried this on [Apache NetBeans 9.0 then download and install it](http://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html), and see if the problem exists on 9.0. If it does then [create a bug report for NetBeans 9.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-376?jql=project%20%3D%20NETBEANS%20AND%20text%20~%20%22certificate%22).

Comment: We are using netbeans 8.2, i have already looked at this bug report before, we intend to migrate to netbeans 9 only into the begin of next year.

Answer (score -1):

A number of plug-ins in `Plugins` window of netbeens are certified with netbeens.org site and they are shown by IDE's icon (in the `Source` column of َ`Available Plugins` tab). If you install one of theme you won't see the alert.
But if you install plugins from other sources you will see this alert.Also you add other plugin sources from `Settings` tab(in `Plugins` window).

Comment: we are creating our own application based into the netbeans platform, https://netbeans.org/features/platform/

Comment: But the poster is using a trusted certificate, so NetBeans should not be giving a bogus warning.